# trouble with a correlated subquery, inner query cannot find column

Tags: sql, sqlite, subquery

i have been having for SQL trouble, i am using an SQLite database and can sadly not get the following to work. All help is appreciated.

I want the following query to sum all integers in the amount column of transactionTable fitting the criteria. One of the criteria changes from row to row in the outer query, so i want the inner query to run one time for every row in the outer query.

i get the following error when running this query:  "no such column: ct.name"
i have bolded the line that i think is wrong in the query below.

table 1 : categoryTable

```
columns: id, icon, name, starred
```

table 2 : transactionTable

```
columns: id, date, amount, sign, category
```

query:

```
SELECT id, icon, name, starred, mySum 
    FROM categoryTable ct, 
         (SELECT sum(amount) AS mySum FROM transactionTable 
          WHERE date<'1992' AND date>'1990' 
          AND sign = '-' AND category=ct.name) AS sumTable 
    WHERE mySum!=0 
    ORDER BY mySum DESC
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this can be done without the subquery. Try this version.

```
SELECT ct.id, ct.icon, ct.name, ct.starred, SUM(tt.amount) AS transactionSum 
    FROM categoryTable ct
        INNER JOIN transactionTable tt
            ON ct.name = tt.category
                AND tt.date < '1992' 
                AND tt.date > '1990'
                AND tt.sign = '-'
    GROUP BY ct.id, ct.icon, ct.name, ct.starred
    HAVING SUM(tt.amount) != 0
    ORDER BY transactionSum DESC
```